# How to Add Dates to Variogram titles using lapply

Tags: r

I have a list of tracking dataframes filtered by year. I've managed to write two functions to A) convert these dataframes to telemetry objects using the ctmm package and B) plot variograms for each individual within each dataframe. The only problem is I currently have it set up so that the title of the variogram is the ID of the individual. Since the same individual can be in multiple annual datasets, I'd like to be able to add the year to the title to distinguish which ID-Year combination is being displayed, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Here's what my code looks like so far:

```
#Variogram function
SVF<-function(x){
  SVF<-list()
  for(i in 1:length(x)){    
    SVF[[i]] <- variogram(x[[i]])
    plot(SVF[[i]],main=names(x[i]))
         }}
#Creating a list of all telemetry objects
Tdata<-list(Tdata2000,Tdata2001,Tdata2002,Tdata2003,Tdata2004,Tdata2005,Tdata2006,Tdata2007,
Tdata2008,Tdata2009,Tdata2010,Tdata2011,Tdata2012)

#Applying the variogram function to the list of dataframes
lapply(Tdata,SVF)
```

This code works as far as calculating variograms, but I don't know how to add the year to the title of the variogram. For example, if I have an individual with the ID AB03 who has been tracked in both 2000 and 2001, this code would result in 2 variograms titled AB03, one for 2000 and 2001. Currently, these two plots would have the same title (AB03) and would therefore be hard to distinguish. I'd like to be able to edit the SVF function so it automatically adds the year to the variogram titles (AB03-2000 and AB03-2001). Is there an easy way to do this without having to go back and edit the ID names of every dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the SVF function to take an additional data argument to include in the title. Use the paste() function to concatenate with the date in parentheses.

See if this approach helped you to solve your problem.
Sorry for my english.

```
#Variogram function with date argument
SVF <- function(x, date) {
  SVF <- list()
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {    
    SVF[[i]] <- variogram(x[[i]])
    plot(SVF[[i]], main = paste(names(x[i]), "(", date, ")"))
  }
}

#Creating a list of all telemetry objects
Tdata <- list(Tdata2000, Tdata2001, Tdata2002, Tdata2003, Tdata2004, Tdata2005, Tdata2006, Tdata2007,
              Tdata2008, Tdata2009, Tdata2010, Tdata2011, Tdata2012)

#Applying the variogram function to the list of dataframes with dates
dates <- format(seq(as.Date("2000/01/01"), as.Date("2012/12/31"), by = "year"), "%Y")
lapply(seq_along(Tdata), function(i) SVF(Tdata[[i]], dates[i]))
```